# Should I pursue a math REU despite my hesitancy and lack of skills or am I kidding myself?

Tags: research-process, mathematics, undergraduate, research-undergraduate

I wouldn't consider myself to be the best math student in my undergrad since I have always had trouble independently starting the homework and I'm constantly going to the professor for help in math. I started getting interested in math and fixing my study habits around my sophomore year of college and by then, I really had a weak foundation in Calculus. My grades are a B-/B range in math. My memory is bad  and I do have trouble reasoning but I work really hard but I'm really slow. I'm apprehensive about trying to apply to Math REU programs because there was an instance last summer a group and I did math programs and while everyone was figuring out simple algebraic problems I was behind and panicking. 
But a part of me wants to continue studying math and adequately honing my understanding/skills in math after undergrad so I don't know. I really like the theory behind math and seeing how beautifully it comes together.

Comment: I can't really imagine a situation where you are potentially interested in further study of Math but shouldn't go ahead and apply to REU programs, because they are explicitly designed to help you figure out if research in the field might be right for you (and help you decide if you want to continue on to grad school). I'm having trouble think of any combination of factors that would make me advise you not to give an REU a try anyway, so long as you are potentially interested in further study and are willing to be open to the experience. There are no grades, and very little downside risk.